# How to add universal support existing react project

Tags: reactjs, universal, isomorphic-javascript, webpack-isomorphic-tools

I've created a react redux project, now how do I add some SEO functionalities to project? I do not want to waste much time while refactoring codes.

Answer (score 1):

- You need to setup the redux store on the server and pass its initial state down to the client, so that the server-render and initial client render don't differ
- Not all life cycle functions are called on the serverside, mainly `componentDidMount` is not called. This indeed helps if you want to do some AJAX data fetching (which you only want to do on the client).
- If you are using `react-router` you need to setup the serverside route matching

Here are some more details: [React can be used on server side rendering. What does that mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39466316/react-can-be-used-on-server-side-rendering-what-does-that-mean/39476945#39476945)