# What is Isomorphic way of Rendering in ReactJS

Tags: angular, reactjs, javascript-framework

**Javascript frameworks are not 'Search-Engine Friendly'. Search Engines has a trouble while loading the data Dynamically and finally frameworks create the markup.**

This problem is resolved in React in an Isomorphic way of rendering.  What is this concept actually? How is it different from Angular?

P.S. New to ReactJS. Would appreciate with more conceptualized explanations if any.

Comment: The main difference with Angular is that React SSR is currently synchronous. Any async code in components won't be rendered. You need to design an app to be synchronously hydrated with data instead of using isomorphic `fetch`.

Comment: @AlirezaNoorali Post the Link if possible. Would be helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React can be used on server side rendering. What does that mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39466316/react-can-be-used-on-server-side-rendering-what-does-that-mean)

Comment: @AlirezaNoorali  No, this question is not a duplicate of the one you mention. This question has a requirement to explain the "Isomorphic" rendering concept related to ReactJS. That keyword is not even mentioned on the other post

Answer (score 1):

ReactJS is just javascript and can run in browser but also can run in server. For example a nodejs server after an http request can run react which produces the html markup and then sends that markup to the browser. This is called react server side rendering but also some people call it universal react.

There are online tutorials/lessons about that. You can search about react server side rendering.
Personally i would recommend this lesson https://www.udemy.com/server-side-rendering-with-react-and-redux/ for understanding how it works

Also because ssr is not easy, you can understand how it works but after that i would recommend using nextjs.

Answer (score 0):

SPA frameworks by default have not good SEO because DATA come after page load with AJAX. this mean if you see Source of page 'ctrl+U' in all page title is equal and it is bad for SEO.

see this to do react SSR ([server-side-rendering](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/demystifying-reacts-server-side-render-de335d408fe4)). in SSR data was fetched and Dom of page built.

you can use [nextJs](https://nextjs.org/) if you dont want to use pure way.

see my  react SSR project for example: [malltina.com](http://malltina.com)

Comment: This is also useful:
https://medium.com/@justinjung04/react-server-side-rendering-and-hot-reloading-ffb87ca81a89

Comment: NextJS? What is that one?@MohammedEbrahimiAval and do you mean to say, we don't have AJAX calls in ReactJS?

Comment: @AshfaqueRifaye NextJs is tools like create-react-app but base of this tools is SSR while you can not do SSR with create-react-app and you must eject it.

Comment: @AshfaqueRifaye Isomorphic mean one code render in 2 side and mean in first time (first request) first page render in server and data fetch as http request after load page in other request data get from AJAX and in this time is like equal normal react.

Comment: Okay. I get it. So with only Next.js, you can do SSR. You can't do SSR with just react library alone!! Thanks bro.

Comment: @AshfaqueRifaye you can use just react lib and do SSR with out any tools (pure way) but is not easy! but you can use NextJs tools to develop faster. see my first comment for pure way.